# Read text from an URL on Codename One

Tags: url, codenameone

I'm relatively new to codename one. I'm trying to read text from a pure text url and store the text in a string. I tried using the java IO package but for some reason it doesn't seem to wirk with codename one. Please help.

David.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might not really understand codenameone seeing as you tried to use the Java IO package. But anyway, this code might get you along

```
    ConnectionRequest r = new ConnectionRequest();
    r.setUrl("YOURURLHERE");
    r.setPost(false);

    r.addResponseListener(new ActionListener()
    {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev)
        {
            try
            {
                NetworkEvent event = (NetworkEvent) ev;
                byte[] data= (byte[]) event.getMetaData();
                String decodedData = new String(data,"UTF-8");
                System.out.println(decodedData);

            } catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    });
    NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueue(r);
```

NOTE: Instead of using System.out.println, which works fine for debugging purposes, you probably want to add the text to your application with a GUI component. I'm not sure if this needs to be said, but it won't do any harm stating it again :)

Comment: You can also do something like Util.downloadUrlToStorage() or ConnectionRequest r = new ConnectionRequest(); r.setURL(...); NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueueAndWait(); byte[] data = r.getData();

Comment: Thanks a lot man! Haven't tried it yet, but will soon. And yes, I'm very very noob with codename one, it's probably my 4th day using it since I discovered it. Thanks!

Comment: I tried it but when I run the code, a bunch of messages like this: "Duplicate entry in the queue: com.codename1.io.ConnectionRequest: com.codename1.io.ConnectionRequest@22b3c488" show up in the console.